# In the context of making an electronic signature, how do I clear my canvas element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I'm building a react component that will essentially serve as a method to sign documents, with an option to draw, or type your signature.

I have a minimal reproduction of my work [found here](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/xrk86q?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A13%2C1&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvj6u7r00063b6ghtb5zsuo%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvj6u7r00023b6gm1urwsda%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvj6u7r00033b6gbbe26uvo%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvj6u7r00053b6guijow0z9%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clpvj6u7r00023b6gm1urwsda%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvj6u7r00023b6gm1urwsda%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvj7tv300023b6go5tbvmzn%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A13%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A1%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A13%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A1%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpvj7tv300023b6go5tbvmzn%2522%257D%252C%2522clpvj6u7r00053b6guijow0z9%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvj6u7r00053b6guijow0z9%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpvjb8gl009a3b6g2xloik8m%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvjb8gl009a3b6g2xloik8m%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clpvj6u7r00033b6gbbe26uvo%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvj6u7r00033b6gbbe26uvo%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvjb15h007o3b6gus57cvjm%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpvjb15h007o3b6gus57cvjm%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

My code looks like this

```
export default function App() {
  const typedCanvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = typedCanvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas?.getContext("2d");

    if (canvas && ctx) {
      ctx.font = "32px cursive";
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
      ctx.fillText(inputValue, 10, canvas.height / 2);
    }
  }, [inputValue]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <canvas ref={typedCanvasRef} />
      <input
        placeholder="enter text here"
        type="text"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(event) => setInputValue(event.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

When you type something into the input, the canvas should mirror it. However, when you make a mistake and hit backspace, `fillText` doesn't seem to respect the `inputValue`'s state. Rather it seems to keep drawing.

Would appreciate any insight into this! I have never worked with canvas so I'm a little bit lost here. Thank you!

Comment: `clearRect`? I'd probably search for something like "html clear canvas" or something--seems like a logical first step. `fillText` "respects" `inputValue`--you're just drawing over what's already there.

Comment: Tangential: questions should include relevant code, config, etc. without forcing readers to visit an external link.

Comment: Have you considered looking at how other React signature components `clear()` functions work, such as: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-signature-canvas

Comment: After `if (canvas && ctx) {` add `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)`. Generally speaking, always clear the whole canvas from scratch on every frame/render/update, then redraw everything.